# How can I use Gephi on Mavericks when I have Java 7 installed?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, gephi

I am facing a problem of getting Gephi (the visualization software) to run on my Mavericks. As you might ask, let me tell you, I have tried installing Java 6 from Apple's site but to no avail. Either the software doesn't start, or it won't show the graphs, or it will give nullpointerexception errors. The software is fine on a VMWare running Windows 8 though, but that's not the problem. The problem is getting Gephi to run in my Mac/Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I had installed java 7 and Gehi didn't start, I got an error in the /vat/log/system.log

> Exited with code: 2

At the end, I didn't uninstall java 7 and I installed java 6 from:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

It works!!!

Comment: I am writing a tutorial on my blog Mr. Geek to show a fix too.